# Covariant collection with delegation

Tags: java, generics, collections

**My (distilled) Scenario:**

Let's say I have an interface called `Interface`, and a `class Foo implements Interface`.

I also have a generic iterable "Result" class which among other things delegates to a collection to do the iterable stuff.  The Result class does other stuff not relevant to the question.  So:

```
class Result<E> implements Iterable<E> {

    private Collection<E> delegate;

    public Result(Collection<E> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return delegate.iterator();
    }

    // ... other irrelevant stuff.
}
```

The collection passed into `Result` can potentially be huge, while users of the `Result` object are likely to stop iterating after a few elements (but I have no control over how many).

Then, I have another class, let's call it Query, which internally holds a collection of `Foo`s, but needs to be able to return Result.  It currently looks like this:

```
class Query {
    private Collection<Foo> data;

    public Result<Interface> getAllData() {
        return new Result<Interface>(new ArrayList<Interface>(data));
    }

    // EDIT: Not all Result objects are of Interfaces.
    public Result<SomeUnrelatedInterface> getSomeOtherData() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

So `getAllData` takes a copy of the data (as an `ArrayList<Interface>`), and passes that to the new `Result` for delegation.  This is not ideal for me, as that collection is probably huge, and the receiver of the result probably only needs the first few results.

**Now for the question:**

Can anyone think of way of changing things such that I do not need to take that copy of the concrete collection?

Ideally, I'd like to have `Result`s constructor be `public Result(Collection<? extends E> delegate)` (like most `Collection`s do), and have it somehow adapt that collection to `Collection<E>`, but I have not been able to figure out what that might look like.

Comment: If anyone can suggest I better title, I'd appreciate it :).

Comment: Does the collection holding the results change during iteration? Is it important to return a snapshot?

Comment: No, the collection doesn't change.  In the event that a method needs to return a snapshot, it'd obviously be up to the `Query` object to manage that (take a copy, manage its data differently, etc).

Comment: So why are you passing a copy of the data to the constructor? Is it because if generic typing issues?

Comment: Yep.  You can't pass a Collection<Foo> to a method expecting a Collection<Interface>.  Collection<Foo> can be passed as a Collection<? extends Interface> (which ArrayList can take, hence why I can take a copy).  If I could take a Collection<? extends Interface> in Result's constructor, then this'd all go away, but then that obviously can't be assigned to my delegate member.

Comment: In that case, you should define Result as Result<E extends Interface> and use an unsafe cast (that you know to be safe).

Comment: Sorry, wasn't too clear about that: I have a number of methods on Query, each returning different Result types (there are a number of unrelated Interfaces that each method returns a reference to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, the danger in turning a `Collection<? extends E>` into a `Collection<E>` is that now the caller can put any `E` into it. So you'd have to rule that out and you'd be fine. `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Collection)` does just that and it will even present the result as a `Collection<E>`.

**Edit**:

```
Collection<? extends Interface> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
Collection<Interface> adapted = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(foos);
```

Comment: Don't forget E is an interface.  The intent is that the caller doesn't care how it's implemented, so I *want* it to contain any E.  The caller has no idea about `Foo`s: its just some private implementation returned by a factory or whatever.

Comment: @Martin I amended my answer. I really don't know how interfaces figure into all this.

Comment: Ahh, sorry.  I misread your initial sentence!  Having things as unmodifyable makes a lot of sense, as I wouldn't want the caller modifying the response.  I like that this doesn't require me to change the return type of the Query methods (that would actually be a fairly big change in my case - Query is actually an interface, with a number of implementations, each dealing with different implementations of the underlying data types).

Answer (score 3):

Would the following variant OK for you?

```
class Result<E extends Interface>
 implements Iterable<E> {

    private Collection<E> delegate;

    public Result(Collection<E> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return delegate.iterator();
    }
}
class Query {
    private Collection<Foo> data;

    public Result<? extends Interface> getAllData() {
        return new Result<Foo>(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, oh dear - I can't believe I didn't think of that.  I reckon that'll solve my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I've just confirmed this meets my needs.  Note: E need not extend Interface, but that constraint can be removed from your first line without affecting the solution.

Comment: This just pushes the problem further down the road. At some point you'll need to adapt a `Result<? extends Interface>` to be a `Result<Interface>`.

Comment: @BenSchulz: Not necessarily.  I *think* the caller can say `for (Interface i : q.getAllData())`, right?  `iterator` will return `Iterator<? extends Interface>`, whose `getNext()` can be directly assigned to an `Interface`.  That said, I think your solution is cleaner (no need to publish which implementation of `Interface` the query object is returning), and safer (the extra guarantee that the caller can't change the collection).

Comment: @Martin The same for-each-loop argument could have been made for collections. ;)